# Can't exit full screen PC Settings dialog on Server 2012 R2 via RDP

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, keyboard-shortcuts

I RDP into a Server 2012 machine for work every day. Sometimes the PC Settings dialog shows / or the Search Page shows up by accident. It is full screen. There is no working key combination I can get for the dialog to close. I need to click the red X button.

This is infuriating as (a), I don't want to be using the mouse and (b), moving my mouse to the top right causes my RDP client to slide down its in-process menu covering the button.

Have tried `Esc`, `Alt-F4`, `Ctrl-F4`, `F11`, `Ctrl-Q`, `Ctrl-X`.

I'm able to close the new Start Menu with the `Esc` key just fine.

The machine is up to date with all recommended & important updates.

**EDIT: I've tried `Alt + Space` as suggested.**

For the search results page, all that happens is the search dialog is shown: [image]

Clicking `Alt + Space` in another 'Settings' type page has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having not thought about this for a while I just realised if you `Alt - Tab` away and back the window header is pinned until you click the window body.

It's then easy to click the close button immediately without causing the RDP Menu to slide over it.

I can now return to being angry about other elements of Microsoft UI.

Answer (score 0):

Try **Alt + space**. It should open window dialog in upper left corner. Then use **Close**.

Comment: Doesn't do that. I've updated the question text.

Answer (score 0):

Hover over the RDP app icon (if) pinned to your taskbar.  When the mini-popup of the Remote Desktop window appears, right click on it and a little menu will appear.  Select Restore.  you may have to do this twice but it gives you control of the window with the Remote Desktop Connection border with maximize and minimize icons.  I got stuck here when using 2 oversized monitors and lost the window control (maximize and minimize and close controls) when I went to full screen and couldn't get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Infuriating when the search results cover the entire server desktop including the taskbar. When you are connected via RDP Alt-Tab and Alt-Space apply to the local machine, not the remote server.

The only way I have found is to use Alt-Ctrl-End to send Ctr-Alt-Del to the server, click 'Task Manager' then the search screen gets minimised to the taskbar and you can close it.